# Negating the selection of :host-context() locally

Tags: css, angular

How to properly negate in an Angular component (locally) with `:host-context()` and `:not()`?

For example, say there is a light/dark theme, differing only by `body.dark` (added to "dark" theme) and we need `red` color only in "light" theme with no changes to color in "dark" theme locally (meaning the code should work in the local Angular component SCSS):

In **`foo-bar.component.scss`**:

```
:host-context(:not(.dark)) { 
    color: red; // red color needed only in "light" theme, no changes to color for "dark" theme
}
```

Comment: You could utilize CSS Variables to make your theme work as it should in a more elegant way. You could set the default style for the light theme and then adjust it when it becomes dark (I don't see a reason to use "not").

Answer (score -2):

Use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on your component, which will open your component's style for the entire project. And you can control that by using a class on your component and adding your component-specific style under that class.

Shown in a working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1iwkar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), with your requirements.

This way, you can add your component-specific (for the theme and general styles) in the component itself, without adding them in global styles.css file.

Comment: Thanks, but  the ask is not for "global" style, but on "component" level style. We don't want the other usages be affected. Can this be done ?

Comment: @zaggi I have updated my answer based on your requirement.

Comment: Shyam, again - "the ask is not for "global" style" - this means the code should work locally (i.e. in an Angular component level). Your proposition adds a global style, which means that all `.apply-theme` not in `.dark` will look the same, which is not what we want to achieve. We want the effect only locally - inside one component

Comment: the two components are not identical - you are adding the extra `.my-custom-comp` class to one of the component HTMLs. The ask is for composition of CSS only (nothing outside of CSS), so that when the HTML is under `.dark` the CSS is applied and when not under `.dark` the CSS is not applied.